# What are good sites or blogs for statistical analysis case studies?

Tags: references, internet

I'm NOT looking for articles that focus on presenting R/Python libraries or how-tos on new/cool/advanced techniques or "data science". I AM looking for articles that show how classical, established statistical analysis techniques, such as regression analysis or ANOVA, are used in demographics, politics, psychology, medicine, climatology or any other field.

*Background for question:* I'm a data scientist with a computer science background, trying to learn how to think like a classical statistician. The techniques themselves I can find in any book on statistics, but I want to understand how these techniques are used in practice.